# How to alter the current user’s password with ALTER USER syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m using PostgreSQL and I’d like to know how to change password of my current user. I know I can use `\password`  but I’m curious how to make it with the   `ALTER USER` syntax.

I know that if my current user is e.g. Yui, simply `ALTER USER Yui WITH PASSWORD ‘123’` would work. But can I avoid explicitly setting Yui here?
I tried something like `ALTER USER (SELECT CURRENT_USER) WITH PASSWORD ‘QWE’` but only received syntax error.

Comment: Attention, curly quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USER` is deprecated. From [ALTER USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html)

> ALTER USER is now an alias for ALTER ROLE.

Try:

`ALTER ROLE current_user WITH PASSWORD 'QWE'`;

In Postgres 14+ it can be:

`ALTER ROLE current_role WITH PASSWORD 'QWE'`;

You also can use `SESSION_USER`  if you want access to the user that initiated the session.

See

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html